# Eclipse package explorer: hide derived folders

Tags: java, eclipse

I normally use the Eclipse Package Explorer to navigate through all source code files that I can edit. So most of the time I do not look into derived folders (e.g. target/, src/generated/).

While I can exclude them manually, is there a filter I missed to hide all derived folders in the Package Explorer? This way I only need to mark a folder as derived to hide it from Package Explorer, Search and Open Ressource.

Comment: I don't see anything. It would be possible to write one but that requires a plug-in, there might be something in the Eclipse Marketplace.

Comment: Searched quickly in the marketplace, could not find anything. Most results were different package or project explorers, but not additions to the default one.

Comment: The pre-set filter _Maven build folder_ hides the `target/` folders.

Comment: 1. Unfortunately I cannot find this option. Maybe we have different versions? I am using Eclipse version 2021-09 (4.21.0) (do not know if Package Explorer has separate version).

2. In my case that would only hide 1/5 folders.